# Curve modifier, deformation only on Z axis

Tags: modeling, modifiers

Hi I want to model a staircase rail. But when I try my curve modifier the ramp don't deform along the curve like a real staircase rail should do, only on the z axis... Is there a way to tell blender to only deform my object on the z axis while still following the curve organic form?

Thanks [image]

The basic mesh must be straight, then I will  put an array on it and a curve modifier follow my curve, but the curve modifier don't work like that.. 
..  I want it to adapt to the complex  curve, as you can see, deformation are only occurring vertically, the object is not tangent to the curve!!

Thanks

Comment: please show some screeshots of your object

Comment: Add empty and control with empty

Comment: Do the array? Don't work it will not deform my object along my irregular curve

Answer (score 5):

### Array a Z deformed panel

No, the **Curve modifier** has no option for that yet.

The trick you can go for at the moment is to **Shear** your panel and set up an array modifer that not only offest on the X axis, but also in the Z of the right amount to build a seamsless mesh.

Luckily stairs usually have steps that are evenly spaced on Z, so the linearity of the height growth imposed by the usage of the **Array modifier** should not be a problem in this case.

The curve is now defining only the path of the rail on plan:

[image]

[image]

*Note for example that in the picture there the tile is romboid shaped, not squared shaped.*

[image]

Comment: i see , this technique work if % of tilt/slope is the same all along the stair ? but what if the ramp need to be more tilted/sloped at certain point , for example if the angle of the curve is 10* at the beginning , then 30* at the end , then i cannot make a parametric rail ramp ? right ? 

thanks for the struggle i really appreciate you effort

Comment: That's right, as I pointed out in the question. If you need to change the slope, you can use a lattice modifier to keep a certain degree of non-destructiveness, but it will be hard to guess where to change it.

Comment: Oh wow, Carlo. This is unbelievable. Great work.

Comment: Thanks @RitaGeraghty, you are too kind!

Answer (score 0):

Archipack have a really great fence creator that do the job perfectly

Answer (score 0):

In archipack, use "custom" subs/posts and pick your base shape as object.

Setup a "Slope" vertex group and assign vertices you want to follow the slope of the fence on your custom object.

You must setup the fence in 2 steps, build it straight, then bend so it follow your path in 2d like you do with the curve modifier.

Use a first curve to define the overall slope of your fence, and use "from curve" in fence parameters.

Use another curve with curve modifier to define the 2d path on xy plane (same as you actually do).