# turn splines from 3d into 2d using animation nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

I have a list of splines created using a loop, how can a I turn each one into a 2d spline using animation nodes?

It is important to note I just have the spline there is no no spline object output.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *dimensions* is a property of the *Curve Data Block* not the splines themselves, thus there is no distinction between 2D and 3D for splines.

A 2D curve just ignores the z axis of the spline points and also ignores the tilt and radius of the splines, so you may do that manually if that is your objective.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. My question is realated to the one answered here [link] (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139150/deform-geometry-along-spline-in-animation-nodes/139167?noredirect=1#comment239278_139167). Deforming geometry with splines can get complicated when it is done in 3d space as it considers the tilt of the curve for deformations. I would like to use the same technique from the link above but without any tilt, same thing that was answered [here] (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114469/curve-modifier-deformation-only-on-z-axis#114481) but with no modifiers.

Comment: @JuanManuelLynch I see, in which case, you can just ignore the tilt directly instead of editing the splines. In my answer, you see that we compute the cross product between the tangent and the normal, you can just ignore the normal and compute it yourself. The normal in this case will be the vector perpendicular to the tangent, which is easy to get in 2D. Let me know if you want more details.

Comment: yes please... I've tried myself to find this perpendicular vector but seems my basic math is not up to the task.

Comment: @JuanManuelLynch Feel free to ask a separate question for that then. Maybe titled "Compute the normal of a 2D spline" or something like that.